# How to use stringPropertyInitialization with Object.assign in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a class like

```
export class Config{

    public doSomething: boolean;
    public doSomethingOptionally?: boolean

    constructor(data: {
        doSomething: boolean,
        doSomethingOptionally?: boolean
    }) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

Passing data to constructor this way is really easy and IntelliSense is smart enough to not allow developers creating new instance of `Config` class without specifying `doSomething` property, but it does without `doSomethingOptionally`.

All this works great, but as soon as I enable `strictPropertyInitialization` in `tsconfig.json` I get a bunch of errors because `doSomething` was not initialized.

What is the best workaround for this?

I don't want to:

1. specify default values (objects can be really large)
2. use `doSomething: boolean = {} as any;`
3. assign value in constructor outside the `data` property because there can be a lot of parameters and calling constructor would become too ugly for my taste
4. Make `doSomething` accept undefined values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to let the compiler know what properties are initialized via `Object.assign` using the [definite assignment assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20166)

```
export class Config{

    public doSomething!: boolean;
    public doSomethingOptionally?: boolean

    constructor(data: {
        doSomething: boolean,
        doSomethingOptionally?: boolean
    }) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```